# Robolectric + Gradle NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project set up as follows:

CommonComponents:

-LibraryModule1

-LibraryModule2

-LibraryModule3

...

When I try to run robolectric unit tests in LibraryModule2 that use classes in LibraryModule one, I get the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/myproject/datamodel/R$string

It can recognize the file in LibraryModule1, and access it, but cannot resolve the R dependencies to run the tests.

The funny thing is, the unit tests run fine when I right click on the class in AndroidStudio and select run tests, it only fails when I try to run it with Gradle from the command line.

I have tried adding the library dependency in the project as follows:
    compile project(path: ':LibraryModule1'), but this again does not work from the command line.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? I'm using version 2.5 of gradle.

Thanks,
-Mark